# Breaking line - Android

Tags: java, android, string

How can I break a line automatically into many lines without cutting off words? And the length for each new line will be around 4 words? I have many sentences thus I cannot use `\n`

e.g:

```
If I were you I would go to the cinema with her
```

becomes:

```
If I were you 
I would go to 
the cinema with her
```

Hope see your help soon. Thanks!

Comment: What you tried so far??? your question is not clear...

Comment: Auto Wrap and fix the width

Comment: @Cuong Lak: Do you want to split the Sentence has Multiple Sentence, each having 4 words, For Instance: If I were you I would go to the cinema with her -> If I were you (Line 1)  I Would go to (Line 2) the cinema with her(Line 3), am i right, and are you setting the text in TextView or ListView?

Comment: It's not clear if your question is about using the Android API or about a general method of splitting. "Around four words" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: Around four words or *four* words or a number of maximum chars?  What if the string is "electroencephalography is extraordinarily spectacular"?

Comment: Thanks all you guy for the help, my problem that I need to split the Sentence to Multiple Sentences.

Comment: @SankarGanesh : Yes, this is my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine, based on what you put although I'm not sure you're considering *all* possible cases, a way to get the specific answer you're looking for while taking a few things for granted and not directly relying on "\n" would be...

```
    String s = "If I were you I would go to the cinema with her";
    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
        if(i % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(strings[i] + " ");
    }
```

Alternatively you might consider something like this, which would handle a max width of your text field as opposed to a set number of words since some words may be very long and cause a situation which you're trying to avoid...

```
    int MAX = 20;
    int length = 0;
    String s = "If I were you I would go to the cinema with her.";
    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
        if((length + strings[i].length()) > MAX ) {
            System.out.println();
            length = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(strings[i] + " ");
        length += strings[i].length() + 1;
    }
```

**Edit:**

I did as you requested. This is what I get from the MAX option...

```
If I were you I 
would go to the 
cinema with her and 
abc xyz
```

And this is what I get for the regular...

```
If I were you 
I would go to 
the cinema with her 
and abc xyz
```

Not sure what's happening there, but I will say I jumped the shark on my answer. You've tagged Android and you and I both know `System.out.println()` is a no-no in that environment, at least if you expect to see any results. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you very much BobbyDigital and I really like the second method with MAX width of the text field. But it does not work when I add more 3 new words : String s = "If I were you I would go to the cinema with her and abc xyz"

It printed 3 lines and missing 2 words "abc" and "xyz" http://i5.upanh.com/2013/1118/10//58123301.breakline.jpg

Could you please check this?
Thanks again :)

Comment: @CuongLak: no problem. See the edit for the results of your request and an explanation for my outright foo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to count the number of spaces in a for loop here is a code to demonstrate it.  **please change the variables according to your application**

```
    String tv2 = tv.getText().toString(); // take a string textVIew, you can make it editView
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tv2); // add the string to stringBuilder
    int howManySpaces = 0; // this for counting the spaces.
    for (int i = 0; i < tv2.length(); i++)
    {

        if (tv2.charAt(i) == ' ') //if space found add one to howManySpaces
        {
            howManySpaces += 1;
            Log.d("HMS", String.valueOf(howManySpaces));
        }

        if (howManySpaces == 4) // if howManySpaces == 4 break it to new line
        {
            sb.replace(i, i+1, "\n");
            howManySpaces = 0;
        }
    }

    tvNew.setText(sb.toString()); // add to the new textView the result after breaking.
```

I just tried it right now, with same sentences it gave me the desired result.

feel free to ask me if you didnt understand any part.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code, it worked fine for me, please try this and kindly let me if you have any trouble on this

// Calling the SentenceBreaker method which helps the String to split.

```
sentenceBreaker("If I were you I would go to the cinema with her");
```

// Method which spilts the Sentence

```
private void sentenceBreaker(int noOfWords,String inputSentence){
            boolean previousCharWhiteSpace = true; // just a flag
        boolean initialFlag =false;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int i,count =0;
        for (i = 0; i < inputSentence.length(); i++) {
            if (inputSentence.charAt(i) == ' ' && !previousCharWhiteSpace) {
                wordCount++;
                previousCharWhiteSpace = true;
                if (wordCount == noOfWords) {
                    if(count == 0){
                        inputSentence = inputSentence.substring(0,wordCount)
                                + "\n"
                                + inputSentence.substring(wordCount,
                                        inputSentence.length());
                        wordCount = 0;
                        count=i;
                    }
                    else{
                        inputSentence = inputSentence.substring(count, i)
                            + "\n"
                            + inputSentence.substring(i,
                                    inputSentence.length());
                    wordCount = 0;
                    count=i;
                    }
                }
            } else if (!(inputSentence.charAt(i) == ' ')) {
                previousCharWhiteSpace = false;

            }
        }
        /*
         * the for loop increments the word count if a space is encountered
         * between words,for multiple spaces between words it wont update the
         * counter-hence the use of the boolean flag.
         */
        if (!(inputSentence.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')) {
            wordCount++;
        }
        // just to make sure that we count the last word in the sentence as well
        System.out.println("No of words-" + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Sentence" + inputSentence);
    }
```

> **/* Output */**

**Sentence If I were you**

**I would go to**

**the cinema with her****

Answer (score 0):

As Per Your Requirement..Following logic will be works fine..Please Use it

```
String stT="If I were you I would go to the cinema with her";
        String[] sT=stT.split(" ");
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<sT.length;i++)
        {
            if(i%4==3)
                sb.append(sT[i]+"\n");
            else
                sb.append(sT[i]+" ");

        }
        System.out.print(sb.toString());
```